# How to parse Local JSON (from Asset folder) for building Bible App in android

Tags: android

I am planning to build an app like BIBLE., For this I decided to use Local JSON to Parse the data.
Please share your ideas to get the data from Local JSon.

Comment: what is the content of JSON file?

Comment: Similar to this...
   [ {
      "bookname": "Luke",
        "chapter": "9",
        "verse": "1"     
   
    },
    {
      "bookname": "Luke",
        "chapter": "9",
        "verse": "2"
    },
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Gson to ease your process of converting a JSON object to a Java Object and then you can easily access individual attributes of that Java class using getters and setters. Here is a small example:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("c:\\file.json"));

        //convert the json string back to object
        DataObject obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject.class);

        System.out.println(obj);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read / store local JSON as json objects directly in files or sqlite databases.  Local or from a server working with json is not different

Answer (score 1):

Just use GSon library to load and parse JSON file from assets. A good start could be [here](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/json-parsing-from-assets-using-gson-in-android-tutorial/).